# Large dataset Neural Network Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm working on Neural networks in Matlab and I have a dataset with 420,000 rows (both for the 5 inputs and the target). Is it better to use subsets to train the model? have you experience on this? thank you

I've already tried using the entire dataset but I don't know it's the right way to procede

Comment: You may want to take a basic tutorial on training NNs, any should cover the topic of optimizers and batch sizes

Comment: with or without subsets, for a given dataset, there's an optimal length training sequence, that you obviusly want it not too long. Beyond such optimal length the training becomes repetitive, wasting time that could be used on real data. But if you keep training too short, meaning missing elements of the orthogonal base onto which the complete dataset could be decomposed, then there will be a higher amount of errors while processing real data.